# readEntity on custom class throws MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am developing a RESTful API in Java for a class.
I am using JAX-RS has I followed this tutorial ["JAX-RS Jersey"](https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-rest-security/).
Everything works has expected except when I tried to perform `response.readEntity(MyTable.class)` to create a new `Object` of the `MyTable` class that I have created.
This works fine for a `String.class` has it reads all the `JSON` information as a string, but it cannot parse it to a new `Object` of my custom class.
I've read a lot on this and I have set all the setters and getters for the attributes and an empty `constructor` but it cannot parse the information to a new object of my custom class. I get the `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.beans.MyTable, genericType=class com.beans.MyTable.` error.

## MyTable.java

```
 private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public MyTable() {

    }

    public MyTable(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyTable [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
```

## MyClient.java

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( new ClientConfig().register( LoggingFeature.class ) );
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/App/rest").path("test");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

//Does not work and gives error
MyTable table = response.readEntity(MyTable.class);
System.out.println(table.toString());
```

## MyService.java

```
@PermitAll
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response test() {
        MyTable table = new MyTable();
        table.setId(1);
        table.setName("mesa de teste");

        GenericEntity<MyTable> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<MyTable>(table, MyTable.class);
        return Response.ok().entity(genericEntity).build();
    }
```

## ERROR

```
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.beans.MyTable, genericType=class com.beans.MyTable.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.runInScopeIfPossible(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:112)
    at com.client.MyClient.main(MyClient.java:31)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrap your `MyTable` in a `GenericEntity`?

Comment: No, I was following the tutorial I  linked and in the source folder provided he did it that way.

Comment: Ok, looking at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html) tells me it is used to carry type information in the Response object for, e.g., selecting a suitable `MessageBodyWriter`. Not necessarily needed, but doesn't break your code either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the linked guide, the author created a customer JSON provider using Gson. You need to register this provider with the the `Client`, just as you did in the server side.

```
new ClientConfig()
    .register( LoggingFeature.class )
    .register( GsonMessageBodyHandler.class )
```

Read [chapter 8 and 9 of the Jersey docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html) to learn more about provider and how they are used to serialized and deserialize in Jersey.

Comment: Yes, I can't believe I forgot that. Now there is no error, but something strange happening: printing the `String Object` for testing purposes, I can see the data of the `MyTable Object`, but when accessing directly with a `MyTable` read `Entity` the fields are null...

Comment: Yeah I don't know. If you are getting all the JSON data when you read it as a String, I'm not sure why it's not working with the POJO. Just an aside (not reason for the problem), but `GenericEntity` is no needed in this case on the server side

Comment: Try to make a POST endpoint on the server that accepts a `MyTable` and send the JSON. See if it works. The same deserialization is done on the server side accepting the POJO as would be done on the client with readEntity

Comment: It does work. I created a `MyTable` and sent it with `invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(table, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))` and was able to access the `Object` attributes on the other side. Strange

Comment: Managed to fix, I added `@SerializedName` notations to the `MyTable` class attributes.